# Array replace and added into two arrays using Java

Tags: java, arrays

Actual String before the Scrap

Bibliographic data: US6079404  (A) ― 2000-06-27

```
String h1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hedvalue']/h1"))
            .getText().replace("Bibliographic data:", "").trim();
```

so in h1 got the result for "US6079404  (A) ― 2000-06-27"

my Expected Result:

1.need to store only the value (US6079404 (A) in that h1 String (Note: length Dynamic not a constant)
2.2000-06-27 - how to store this value in another string

Sample o/p

h1 - US6079404 (A1)

h2 - 2000-06-27

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string:

```
String[] parts = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hedvalue']/h1"))
        .getText().replace("Bibliographic data:", "").trim().split(" ― ");
String h1 = parts[0];
String h2 = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression to resolve it.
You also don't need to replace the `Bibliographic data:`.

I suppose that the `.getText()` gives you

```
Bibliographic data:US6079404 (A) ― 2000-06-27
```

RegEx for that string with groups would be like:

```
^Bibliographic data:(.*)\s―\s(.*)$
```

**Java Code**

```
String raw = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hedvalue']/h1")).getText();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Bibliographic data:(.*)\\s―\\s(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raw);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```